# How to find derivative of an integral of this type

Tags: integration, derivatives

$$f(x) = \int _x^{e^x}\:\left(\sin t^2\right)\,dt$$

How to find the derivative $f'(x)$

Attempt: $\sin (e^{x^2})  e^x$

Comment: In general, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\mathrm dt\right)=b'(x)f(b(x))-a'(x)f(a(x))$$
This is a special case of [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), let $F$ be antiderivative of $\sin t^2$, then you have:

$$f(x)=F(e^x)-F(x)$$

So:

$$f'(x)=e^xF'(e^x)-F'(x)=e^x \cdot \sin ((e^{x})^2)-\sin (x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this.

Substitute the values for the upper and lower limits of the integral into the equation. then multiply by the derivative of that value:

So:

$$f'(x) = e^{x}\sin(e^{2x}) - \sin(x^2)$$